# Air ANE and iOS 64bit: pointer to uint32 conversion?

Tags: ios, xcode, air, 64-bit, ane

I'm creating an adobe air extension for iOS, and have a newbie question :)
I get an error

```
....cpp:27:28: Cast from pointer to smaller type 'uint32_t' (aka 'unsigned int') loses information
```

in these lines:

```
FREObject ptr;
FRENewObjectFromUint32((uint32_t)shape, &ptr);
```

:(
FlashRuntimeExtensions.h I've copied from AirSDK18, and I thought it is compatible with iOS 64 bit?..

*Question is simple, but google didnt helped me.

Comment: How is shape defined?

Comment: btCollisionShape* shape = new btCylinderShape(halfExtents);
trying to use bullet physics..

Comment: Why are you trying to return a pointer to a native object to flash?